# How to send e-mail through G-mail account with out prompting user

Tags: android

I have a service, and in that Service I have been sending some data through mail. For that I am using the Gmail account. To send the mail. I have searched  a lot but not able to get the right answer.

I can not send mail through Intent as I do not want to show it to user. All I want is that to send mail in the service with out notifying the user.

For this I have followed [this](https://www.mindstick.com/Articles/1673/sending-mail-without-user-interaction-in-android) tutorial but It is not ending the mail. It just shows toast "Mail Sent" but in fact It does not send message I have checked the inbox and sent items as well but there is nothing

I have not get any exception. But still it is not working .

Please help . If you know any working solutions.

Comment: Check-out this tutorial:- http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_(no_Intents)_in_Android

Comment: You need to show the code that is not working. Also, if I ever catch an app sending an email from my account without clear disclosure, I'll uninstall and report it immediately.

Comment: thanks @2Dee for your valuable information , which I do not know .

Comment: @AllayKhalil ;- Check-out this one too http://stackoverflow.com/a/2033124/1384010

Comment: @adrash yadav but when I changed my google setting to secure , then this code is unable to send the mail

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can, now, send email programatically. You need to use [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/?hl=en)

According to Gmail API,

**To create message:**

```
/**
   * Create a MimeMessage using the parameters provided.
   *
   * @param to Email address of the receiver.
   * @param from Email address of the sender, the mailbox account.
   * @param subject Subject of the email.
   * @param bodyText Body text of the email.
   * @return MimeMessage to be used to send email.
   * @throws MessagingException
   */
  public static MimeMessage createEmail(String to, String from, String subject,
      String bodyText) throws MessagingException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

    MimeMessage email = new MimeMessage(session);
    InternetAddress tAddress = new InternetAddress(to);
    InternetAddress fAddress = new InternetAddress(from);

    email.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    email.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO,
                       new InternetAddress(to));
    email.setSubject(subject);
    email.setText(bodyText);
    return email;
  }
```

**To send message:**

```
  /**
   * Send an email from the user's mailbox to its recipient.
   *
   * @param service Authorized Gmail API instance.
   * @param userId User's email address. The special value "me"
   * can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
   * @param email Email to be sent.
   * @throws MessagingException
   * @throws IOException
   */
  public static void sendMessage(Gmail service, String userId, MimeMessage email)
      throws MessagingException, IOException {
    Message message = createMessageWithEmail(email);
    message = service.users().messages().send(userId, message).execute();

    System.out.println("Message id: " + message.getId());
    System.out.println(message.toPrettyString());
  }
```

Check the link: [Sending Email](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending)

Comment: @AllayKhalil You can start from here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/android